# How to get a Node.js REST client to be able to communicate with a ServiceStack JSON Service

Tags: node.js, servicestack

I'm having issues getting a rest client written in Node.js to be able to send data (via GET) to a ServiceStack JSON-based Service.  It's giving me a serialization error.  However, I've copied and pasted the same JSON (generated by my Node.js rest client) into a call to the ServiceStack Service sent via CURL and ServiceStack isn't having an issue with the JSON--again...only as long as it is coming from CURL.

Any pointers or further enlightenment anyone can shed will be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Tami

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I figured out how to get the above working in Node.js and not just in CURL (sending/receiving JSON to a ServiceStack JSON service).

I did the following:

- Use the "restler" package as my http communication wrapper
- Use the "get()" method of restler...DO NOT USE THE "json()" METHOD
  (Code snippet follows...)

  ```
  var obj = {};
  obj.objectName = 'foo';
  obj.foos = [{firstname: 'foo1', lastname: 'foo-you'}, {firstname: 'foo2', lastname: 'foo-you-2'}];
  var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
  var options = {
      method: "get",
      data: json,
      headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
  };
  rest.get('http://localhost/servicestack-api/getmethod', options).
      on('complete', function(data, response){
          console.log(data);
          console.log(response.statusCode);

      });
  ```
- Make sure to fill in the above with the correct url and remote DTO to your ServiceStack service and method

**FYI**

If your json does not serialize to the remote DTO in ServiceStack, a quick way to test would be to copy and paste the json stored in the "json" variable above into a curl command to see if it serializes correctly that way.
(Sample curl snippet below...)

This is what I did initially (see original question) to try to trouble-shoot serialization issues.  It helped me isolate the problem to the restler/Node.js side so I could make the modifications you see above--namely NOT using the "json()" method of restler.

```
    curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET -d '{"foos":[{"firstname":"foo1","lastname":"foo-you"}, {"firstname": "foo2", "lastname": "foo-you-2"}],"objectName": "foo"}' http://localhost/servicestack-api/getmethod
```